# Dynamic creation of list view dosen't show multiple rows in android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-listview, sms, android-gridview

Being a newbie to android I am trying to implement List view on my project. The list view works. However I am only able to see one row in my list. I wish to add as many rows as I want dynamically.
I have created a separate XML which defines the structure of a single row in the list view.
Here is what I have coded until now :

```
public class Offers extends Activity 
{
    ListView latesttrans;

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_offers);
        latesttrans = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        latesttrans.setAdapter(new mylist2(this));
    }
}
    class SingleRow2
    {
        String title;
        String description;
        SingleRow2(String title, String description)
        {
            this.title=title;
            this.description=description;
        }
    }
    class mylist2 extends BaseAdapter
    {
        int i=0;
        Boolean flagValue = false;
        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        Context context;
        mylist2(Context c)
        {
            context=c;
            list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
            Resources res = c.getResources();
            String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
            String[] description = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);

                list.add(new SingleRow(title[i],description[i]));
                i++;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_offers,viewGroup,false);

            Uri latesttransuri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor latesttranscursor = context.getContentResolver().query(latesttransuri, new String[]{"_id","address","date","body"}, null, null, null);

            if(flagValue == false)
            {
                latesttranscursor.moveToFirst();
                flagValue = true;
            }

            String address = null,body = null;
            int i=0;

                while(latesttranscursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    address=latesttranscursor.getString(1);
                    long date = latesttranscursor.getLong(2);
                    String sdate = millisToDate(date);
                    body = latesttranscursor.getString(3);

                    if(body.contains("FREE"))
                    {
                        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleOffer1);
                        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleOffer2);
                        title.setText(address);
                        description.setText(body);
                    }
                    else if(body.contains("unlimited"))
                    {
                        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleOffer1);
                        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleOffer2);
                        title.setText(address);
                        description.setText(body);
                    }

                }

            return row;
        }
        public String millisToDate(long currentTime) 
        {
            String finalDate;
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);
            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            finalDate = date.toString();
            return finalDate;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't iterate over your items. In the constructor of your adapter you just increment i once, and then stop. This results in having one row. Change it to a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < var; i++) {
  list.add(new SingleRow(title[i], description[i]));
}
```

Where var is the size of your array that you retrieve from the resources.

For more information about ListView and the use of Adapters: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: The thing is I am dynamically creating the list. The app will fetch the sms from inbox and then based upon the rules that I have defined in my getView() method, it will populate the list.

Comment: But the adapter is only populated with an ArrayList that has just one item. It will call the getView() just one time because of that.

Comment: Ok. So How can I get the adapter to be populated with multiple sms rows based upon the rules that I define in my getView() method ?

Comment: Let your adapter implement the class ArrayAdapter<SingleRow> then add the constructor mylist2(Context context, int layout, List<SingleRow> objects). Now the getView method is called for every item in the list you passed trough your constructor. You can retrieve them by creating a field List<SingleRow> in your ArrayAdapter and calling the objects from there with the position parameter in your getView method!

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand you.

Comment: @TechFrk This will certainly help you out: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter